# PCA on text data in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

I want to use [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) to reduce our features (columns) in a dataset, but one of the features is a text feature.

For this, our solution was convert text features to numeric, how can we do this?

Or is there another solution to use PCA on text features?

For example, this dataframe:

[image]

Comment: It's my question too, You can check Dimensionality Reduction methods.

Answer (score 0):

For the text, you can build vectors from text.
List of vectorizers in scikit-learn that work on text can be found here - https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.feature_extraction.text.

Answer (score 0):

PCA finds the axis of the data with the greatest variance. For this all the inputs must be numerical.

You could take the length of the text string, that would provide a number, but it is unlikely that will provide any useful information. Ultimately, it is up to you to decide what you want from the data and that will inform how to change this. If your text field is categorical one way is to can create dummy variables that split a categorical variable into multiple binary variables. You can do this in Pandas with the get_dummies method.

In my opinion, a better question to ask is why you want to reduce your feature set and if the text is even relevant to your analysis.